# How do I customise the toolbar in Notepad++ without using a plug-in?

Tags: notepad++

I'd like to add a separator (vertical line a bit like `|`) to the Notepad++ toolbar, between the options for the `Compare` plug-in and the `XML Tools` plug-in. I've tried to install the `Customize Toolbar` plug-in, but it won't install.

Is there a config file I can edit to add a separator, manually?

Comment: I have successfully installed the Customize Toolbar plugin via *Plugins > Plugins Admin...* with no problem.

Comment: @harrymc I don't know why it won't stick. It says it's ready to go, I click install, NPP restarts, but alas no extension. I might try running NPP as admin...

Comment: Nope. I get the dialog "downloading customize plugin", which closes after a few seconds, and then it's not showing under Installed.

Comment: You could uninstall NPP, cleanup all folders and try again.

Comment: Uninstall NPP? Yeah, I might have to... or I can just live without a separator.